# Why doesn't extending Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.Page class work with layout and partial views?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, razor, asp.net-core-mvc, razor-pages

I am trying to extend `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.Page` in all views to provide extra functionalities. Extending `Page` class and using `@inherits` in `_ViewImports` works fine in razor pages but errors occur with `_Layout` and partial views.

I added the following in `_ViewImports`:

```cs
@inherits WebApplication1.Razor.CustomRazorPage
```

Where:

```cs
public abstract class CustomRazorPage : Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.Page
{
    public string SayHi(string name)
    {
        return $"Hi <strong>{name}</strong>";
    }
}
```

But that produced the following errors:

```
1>Pages\Shared\_Layout.cshtml(6,13,6,21): error CS0103: The name 'ViewData' does not exist in the current context
1>Pages\Shared\_Layout.cshtml(35,14,35,24): error CS0103: The name 'RenderBody' does not exist in the current context
1>Pages\Shared\_Layout.cshtml(49,7,49,20): error CS0103: The name 'RenderSection' does not exist in the current context
```

To overcome this issue, I had to add the following at the top of `_Layout` file:

```cs
@inherits Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorPage<TModel>
```

However, I still face troubles with partial views in which I could not get any success even when adding an explicit `@inherits` for either `RazorPage<TModel>` nor `CustomRazorPage`:

```
Error   CS0103  The name 'Model' does not exist in the current context
```

I've added the sample code in this github repo: [aspcore-extend-razor-page-issue](https://github.com/houmamwazzeh/aspcore-extend-razor-page-issue) (check `index.cshtml`)

Comment: I've checked the issue with an MVC project and it worked like a charm. I've just extended `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorPage<TModel>` and declared it with `@inherits` in _ViewImports. Example in [aspcore-extend-razor-page-mvc](https://github.com/houmamwazzeh/aspcore-extend-razor-page-mvc)

Comment: So, the concept works fine with MVC project but not with Razor Pages.

Answer (score 2):

It turns out that we should explicitly add `@inherits` for the partial view as the same as in `_Layout` file. So, the partial view [_Hello.cshtml](https://github.com/houmamwazzeh/aspcore-extend-razor-page-issue/blob/master/WebApplication1/Pages/_Hello.cshtml) should be as follows:

```cs
@inherits Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorPage<TModel>
@model WebApplication1.Pages.Models.HelloModel

<div class="alert alert-success">Welcome to our Partial View @Model.Name</div>
```

But, in this case, we will not be able to get benefit from the extra functionality that `CustomRazorPage` provides. However, we can extend the `RazorPage<TModel>` in the same manner to provide the same functionality that `CustomRazorPage`.

I am not sure if there is another overcome to this issue. But it looks like the `_Layout` file and partial views have difference context from other Razor Pages.

### Update 11/19/2019

More details found in this issue that I had posted before:

- https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/17189#issuecomment-555490265